# How to generate an instance of an unknown type at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, types, runtime

i've got the following in C#:

```
string typename = "System.Int32";
string value = "4";
```

theses two strings should be taken to generate an object of the specified type with the specified value...

result should be:

```
object o = CreateUnknownType(typename, value);
...
Int32 test = (Int32)o;
```

Comment: And your question is? Why try to create an unknown if you are going to cast it to a known type later?

Comment: Question is: How to generate an instance of an unknown type at runtime? It doesn't matter why or wyh not, i just want to know if its possible

Comment: That's easy then, yes it's possible. Is it practicable? Probably not. Was it unreasonable to ask for some context when your example doesn't make sense?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Is this what are you are thinking?

```
object result = Convert.ChangeType("4", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
```

Answer (score 18):

As stated, this is too broad and can not be solved generally.

Here are some options:

```
Type type = Type.GetType(typename);
object o = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

This will create an instance of the type that `typename` is describing. It calls the parameterless constructor of that type. (Downside: Not all objects have a parameterless constructor. Further, this does set the state of the object using `value`.)

```
Type type = Type.GetType(typename);
object o = Activator.CreateInstance(type, new[] { value });
```

This will create an instance of the type that `typename` is describing. It calls a constructor of that type that accepts one parameter of type `string`. (Downside: Not all objects have such a constructor. For example, `Int32` does not have such a constructor so you will experience a runtime exception.)

```
Type type = Type.GetType(typename);
object o = Convert.ChangeType(value, type);
```

This will attempt to convert the string `value` to an instance of the required type. This can lead to `InvalidCastException`s though. For example, `Convert.ChangeType("4", typeof(FileStream))` will obviously fail, as it should.

In fact, this last example (create an instance of type `FileStream` with its initial state determined by the string `"4"`) shows how absurd the general problem is. There are some constructions/conversions that just can not be done.

You might want to rethink the problem you are trying to solve to avoid this morass.

Answer (score 3):

Creating an instance of a type you know by name (and which should have a default constructor):

```
   string typeName = "System.Int32";
   Type type = Type.GetType(type);
   object o = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Parsing a value from a string will obviously only work for a limited set of types. You could

- use `Convert.ChangeType` as suggested
  by PhilipW
- or maybe create a
  `Dictionary<Type,Func<string,object>>`
  which maps known types to known parse
  functions
- or use reflection to invoke the
  Parse(string) method on the type,
  assuming there is one:

  ```
     string valueText = "4";
     MethodInfo parseMethod = type.GetMethod("Parse");
     object value = parseMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { valueText });
  ```
- or maybe you can use the
  infrastructure provided by the .NET
  component model. You can fetch the
  type converter of a component and use
  it like this:

  ```
     TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type);
     object value = converter.ConvertFromString(valueText);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic seems a little flawed here.  Obviously, if you're directly casting the object at a later time to the actual type it is, then you must know the type to begin with.

If there's something else that is missing from this question please elaborate and maybe there is a more appropriate answer than simply, "This doesn't make much sense."

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have a set of different types, all of which implement a known interface?

For example if you have several different user controls and want to load one of them into a container, each one might implement IMyWobblyControl (a known interface) yet you might not know until runtime which of them to load, possibly from reading strings from some form of configuration file.

In that case, you'll need to use reflection to load the actual type from something like the full assembly name, then cast it into your known type to use it.

Of course, you need to make sure that your code handles invalid cast, assembly not found and any of the other exceptions that are likely to come along through something as wobbly as this...

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a job for Int32.Parse(string).  But to agree with the others it seems this is "unique" and one should probably think gloves.

Answer (score 0):

After using:

```
Type type = Type.GetType(typename);
```

Try this extension method:

```
public static class ReflectionExtensions
{
    public static T CreateInstance<T>(this Type source, params object[] objects)
        where T : class
    {            
        var cons = source.GetConstructor(objects.Select(x => x.GetType()).ToArray());
        return cons == null ? null : (T)cons.Invoke(objects);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a specific example of the problem involving Azure SQL Federations...which splits data into separate db's according to a key range.

The key range types are:

**SQL**                    / **.Net SQL type**     / **CLR .Net**

INT                        / SqlInt32              / Int32, Nullable

BIGINT                     / SqlInt64              / Int64, Nullable

UNIQUEIDENTIFIER           / SqlGuid               /Guid, Nullable

VARBINARY(n), max n 900    / SqlBytes, SqlBinary    /Byte[]

Ideally, a C# function param could take either .Net SQL type or CLR .Net type but settling on just one category of type is fine.

Would an "object" type param be the way to go?  And, is there a feasible way to identify the type and convert it accordingly?

The concept is something like:

public void fn(object obj, string fedName, string distName, bool filteringOn)

{

...figure out what type obj is to ensure it is one of the acceptable types...

string key = obj.toString();

return string.Format("USE FEDERATION {0} ({1}='{2}') WITH RESET, FILTERING = {3}", fedName, distName, key, (filteringOn ? "ON" : "OFF"));

}

Though the param value is cast to string, it will be recast/checked on the sql server side so validating it on the app side is desired.