# Non-default constructor for runtime determined type

Tags: c#, reflection, constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Activator.CreateInstance - How to create instances of classes that have parameterized constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288310/activator-createinstance-how-to-create-instances-of-classes-that-have-paramete)

I was wondering how to create an object of a type determined at runtime without using the default constructor.

That is, I have `BaseClass` and various child classes.

```
Type type; //this variable will be one of the child classes
BaseClass base = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

This allows me to create a child class object with the default constructor, but I'd like to call a specific constructor. I know all of the child classes have a constructor taking certain parameters, so I have no worries of that constructor not existing. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722491/how-to-generate-an-instance-of-an-unknown-type-at-runtime) question, but the best I can get there is a single string parameter. Is this doable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288310/activator-createinstance-how-to-create-instances-of-classes-that-have-paramete#answer-1288333

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three options:

- Use [`Type.GetConstructor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getconstructor.aspx) and then [`ConstructorInfo.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ycw1y17.aspx)
- Use [one of the overloads of `Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) which takes arguments.
- If you already know all the possible types beforehand, create a `Dictionary<Type, Func<string, string, YourBaseType>>` or whatever's appropriate

The third option requires you to change your factory code each time you add a new type, of course - but it's only a single line.

Personally I like the first option, as it gives you the most control (rather than relying on `Activator.CreateInstance` finding the best matching constructor at execution time) - and if this is performance-sensitive code, you could build a dictionary of delegates at execution time by discovering the constructors, then using expression trees. (As far as I can tell, you can't build a delegate from a constructor using `Delegate.CreateDelegate`, which is somewhat annoying.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Activator.CreateInstance(Type, Object[])` overload to do this. It'll call most sutable constructor based on parameters provided.

For example:

```
public class Test{
 public Test(){
    Console.WriteLine("Defaul ctor");
 }

 public Test(int i){
    Console.WriteLine("Test(int)");
 }

 public  Test(int i, string s){
    Console.WriteLine("Test(int, string)");
 }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var o1 = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Test));
    var o2 = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Test), 1);
    var o3 = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Test), 1, "test");
}
```